# Как сделать код, что заполнит процессор и его ядра на 100%!

Tags: python, python-3.x, threading

Как сделать код, который загрузит ядра на 100%.

Comment: Сам себе ответчик:-) И как же его сделать? `threading` вам точно ядра не заполнит, он по умолчанию на одном ядре работает.  Советую ознакомиться с документацией.

Answer (score 1):

[multiprocessing.cpu_count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.cpu_count) возвращает число процессоров в системе. [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) создаёт пул процессов по числу процессоров. [Pool.map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) загружает их бесполезной работой: запускает бесконечный цикл в функции `f`.

```
import multiprocessing


def f(_):
    while True:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(n) as p:
        p.map(f, [None] * n)
```

**P.S.** Запуск нескольких нитей внутри одного процесса не поможет из-за [GIL (global interpreter lock)](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock).

Answer (score 0):

**Код безобиден, но лучше использовать на хороших ПК.**

```
from threading import Thread

class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        for i in range(1000000):
            msg = "%s is running" % \
                self.name
            print(msg)


def create_threads():
    for i in range (10000):
        name = "Thread #%s" % (i + 1)
        my_thread = MyThread(name)
        my_thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_threads()
```

Comment: На моём компьютере нагрузка получилась жалкие 30%

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i in range(100000000): 
  for a in range(100000000): 
    print(a)
```

Что может быть проще?)

Comment: Вы загрузите таким образом только один процессор.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну тогда раскидать этот код по всем ядрам и всё

Comment: `2**99999999999`

Comment: Два в степень Питон возводит очень быстро. Просто забьёт всю память нулями и падёт. Естественно, всё на одном процессоре.